# Neomodel filter on relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neomodel

I'm having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to filter a Neomodel NodeSet based on a relationship.  I have a class `Patient` that has a relationship `GENDER` that points to a node with the label `Gender`. 
My classes looks like this:

```
Class Patient(StructuredNode):
patient_id = StringProperty()
gender = RelationshipTo('Gender', "GENDER")

Class Gender(StructuredNode):
gender = StringProperty()
patient = RelationshipTo('Patient', "HAS")
```

I start by filtering `Patient` by a query string which returns a NodeSet called `patients`. I now want to filter `patients` by gender.  What I have is:

```
patients = NodeSet((NodeSet(patients.gender).filter(gender=gender).patient)
```

This works but I'm wondering if there is an easier way or better way??